# Remote access jupyter notebook on Windows 10

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, dhcp

My home network environment is using **DHCP**, the router uses **D-link 600m**, I want to make remote access jupyter notebook on Windows 10.

Here are the steps I used:

Windows network part:

1. Open command: Enter ipconfig /all to get my private ip, subnet mask, default gateway.
   [image]
2. Go to the D-link settings page:
   fix the dhcp ip with private ip & mac address
   [image]

then go to the virtual server, enter the virtual ip, port 8000
[image]

3. Open windows network, change IPv4 settings to fixed ip, private ip, subnet mask, default gateway
   [image]
4. Open windows firewall -> advanced settings -> Inbound Rules to add port 8000
   [image]

Jupyter notebook part:

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html
I am sure this part is ok.

When I done these two parts, I open whatismyip.com to check my public ip. 
And, I type https://[my public ip]:8000. It shows nothing but ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Please help me, thanks !

Comment: Have you used --ip command? to run the jupyter notebook

Comment: yes, I change the jupyter_config -> c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did.
generate config file.

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
jupyter notebook password
```

edit file /users//.jupyter/../jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Allow TCP, inbound, port firewall

However, this is just for fast test. You should add https cert to avoid getting hacked.